# Searching multiple patterns within selected filenames in batch

Tags: regex

Example:

```
Set pat1='ab'
Set pat2=de-fu

For %%i in (*.xml) do (
  Find in %%i filename the following pattern:
     Anything+%pat1%+followed by a number 1-2 [1-2]+anyting+%pat2%
)
```

Basically what is important is to match in the xml filename (not in contents):

```
%pat1%[1-2] + %pat2%
```

1. Pat1 content can be anywhere in filename
2. [1 OR 2] Have to be exactly after pat1 contents.
3. Content of pat2 should be at the of the filename or anywhere, doesnt matter.
4. Be able to apply action on the file if the pattern is matched.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Sincerely,
Thanos

Comment: I used something like this for now and it seems to covering the most of the cases. Hopefully. It will be nice if there is an improved approach:                                                                                             echo.!Name! | findstr /R /I "[^-]%%a[12\']..">Nul && (     SET Flag=1
 Echo Flag: !Flag!
) || (
 Echo Checking .......
)
echo.!Name! | findstr /I %%b>Nul && (
 IF !Flag!==1 (
    Echo File: !Name!: Match: "[^-]%%a[12\'].." AND %%b
 )
) || ( 
 Echo Checking.......
)

Answer (score 1):

I used something like this for now and it seems to covering the most of the cases. Hopefully. It will be nice if there is any improved approach:

```
echo.!Name! | findstr /R /I "[^-]%%a[12\']..">Nul && (
    SET Flag=1
) || (
    Echo Checking .......
)
echo.!Name! | findstr /I %%b>Nul && (
   IF !Flag!==1 (
      Echo File: !Name!: Match: "[^-]%%a[12\'].." AND %%b
   )
) || ( 
   Echo Checking.......
)
```